# Rails Model Validation converts & to &amp;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I disabled all the validations in the model but when i try to access the following. It converts string having & to &

---

```
p = Project.new(title: 'With & character')
p.valid?
p.title 
=> "With &amp; character"
```

There is no Validation in the model. any idea why it is behaving like this ? using Rails 4.2.4

my Model code

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
```

Comment: what database character set `utf8` ? utf8_general_ci collation mysql

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `encoding: utf8` in `database.yml`

If above doesn't works, then you could use something like this:

```
CGI::unescapeHTML(your_string)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: encoding is there but i also tried  CGI::unescapeHTML but it doesnt work.
          
   p = Project.new(title: CGI::unescapeHTML('Yes & no'))

Comment: I even deleted all the code in Model, just kept the class declaration and still the result is same.

Comment: @Kashif Could you use double quotes `"` in place of single quotes `'`.

Comment: `class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

 This is class definition 
`p = Project.new(title: CGI::unescapeHTML("Yes & no"))`

same result

Comment: I tried in one other model in the same application and its fine with normal code without unescapeHTML and its not converting & into &amp;

This is weird case, I've been facing last 1 hour :(

Comment: Dusht - added the code in description of the Question